# Authorize.Net Direct Post - MD5 to SHA

Tags: magento-1.9

today i got a message to update my Magento Shop with a new patch (MD5 Algorithm to SHA).
How can i check, if my shop needs that update too? I never heard about "Authorize.Net Direct Post payment method".

Currently I am using "SaferPay" and Authorize.Net is not showing up for payment methods. So im not using it?!

Thank you
Chris

Comment: Hello @Christian, did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Earlier Authorize.net using `MD5` as a encryption algorithm. Now they are upgrading and going with `Signature Key (SHA-512)` encryption.

As, all existing Magento using earlier encryption, So all Magento need to Patch (Replace some files) to correctly working of `Authorize.net` as a payment method.

If you not using Authorize.net as payment method (also planning not to be use in future): **Don't do anything just ignore this message**

If you are using it, you need to apply patch as per official given [document.](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392)

Comment: does this issue affect the "Authorize.net" payment method that's in Mage_Paygate?  I think they are different and separate but would like some confirmation.  Thanks!